# How to make a text color transition without CSS?

Tags: java, javafx, colors

I've made a dummy project just to show what is trying to be made. I'm going for a transition on color for text without CSS (as I just can't wrap my head around CSS). In the dummy project, the text starts from red

[image]

then goes to blue

[image]

Found out about `FillTransition` though that only works with shapes, so this would be a similar function. My other attempt was trying to get the RGB values of both colors then stick them in a `do while` with a new `Color` just to test it out though the transition is almost instant as the application starts so it changes the color but without transitioning effect. I'm thinking of making an `Timeline` for this similar to the `do while` but I haven't tried that yet.

Before going into this what are some ways to make this effect?

Here's the dummy code:

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            StackPane stack = new StackPane();
            
            Text text = new Text("Hello there StackOverflow, how are you? (:");
            
            Color color1 = Color.RED;
            Color color2 = Color.BLUE;
            
            double r1 = color1.getRed();
            double g1 = color1.getGreen();
            double b1 = color1.getBlue();
            
            double r2 = color2.getRed();
            double g2 = color2.getGreen();
            double b2 = color2.getBlue();
            
            Color colorEffect = new Color(r1, g1, b1, 1.0);
            
            stack.setLayoutX(200);
            stack.setLayoutY(200);
            
            text.setFont(Font.font(16));
            text.setFill(colorEffect);
            
            stack.getChildren().add(text);
            root.getChildren().add(stack);
            
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`Color`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/paint/Color.html) implements `Interpolatable`, you can use it directly as a `KeyValue` in a `Timeline`, without the need for a custom interpolator.

[image]

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.KeyValue;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74249258/230513
 */
public class FillAnimation extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("FillAnimation");
        var color1 = Color.RED;
        var color2 = Color.BLUE;
        var text = new Text("Hello, StackOverflow!");
        text.setFill(color1);
        text.setStyle("-fx-font-family: serif; -fx-font-size: 42;"
            + "-fx-font-style: oblique; -fx-font-weight: bold");
        var timeline = new Timeline();
        var c = new KeyValue(text.fillProperty(), color2, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH);
        var k = new KeyFrame(new Duration(1000), c);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(k);
        timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
        var root = new StackPane(text);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        var scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Text`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/text/Text.html) is a shape, so [`FillTransition`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/FillTransition.html) works on text, because it operates on any kind of shape.

This effect demonstrated in this answer is the same as that demonstrated in [trashgod's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74249258/1155209) answer, (the code is based on trashgod's code), it just uses a transition rather than a timeline.

The example uses the default [interpolator](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Transition.html#interpolatorProperty), [`EASE_BOTH`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Interpolator.html#EASE_BOTH), to interpolate between the interpolatable `Color` values, but you can set a custom interpolator if desired.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class TextFillTransitionApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        var text = new Text("Hello, StackOverflow!");
        text.getStyleClass().add("styled-text");

        FillTransition textFillTransition = new FillTransition(
                Duration.seconds(1),
                text,
                Color.RED,
                Color.BLUE
        );

        textFillTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        textFillTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

        var layout = new StackPane(text);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        layout.getStylesheets().add(CSS);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();

        textFillTransition.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final String CSS_DATA = "data:text/css,";
    private static final String CSS = CSS_DATA + // language=CSS
            """
            .styled-text {
                -fx-font-family: serif;
                -fx-font-size: 42;
                -fx-font-style: oblique;
                -fx-font-weight: bold
            }
            """;
}
```

Comment: I see, so there's two different ways of doing it. Didn't realize you just had to put the values of the colors along with the text afterwards. This is good to know, Thank you @jewelsea!